# Post image from an Ionic App to PHP Server

Tags: image, cordova, ionic-framework, phpmailer

I am building up a mobile app using Ionic Framework. I need to let the users select an image from their phone gallery(using Cordova ImagePicker) and click on the Upload button. Once the user clicks the Upload button, the image and the username has to be passed to the server and the server then handles both the image and the usernmae and mails it across to a designated email id using the PHPMailer Class. As of now, I am successful in sending the username to the server and successfully forward it as an email, but I lack idea about how to send the image alongwith it.

Please help!

**Note: I don't want to upload the image to the server at all or I could have used Cordova File Transfer plugin.I just want to pass the image to the PHPMailer class and mail it.**

Client Side

```
.controller('UploadCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaImagePicker,$http) {

    $scope.collection = {
        selectedImage : ''
    };

    $scope.takePicture = function() {   
         var options = {
                maximumImagesCount:1, 
                width: 800,
                height: 800,
                quality: 80        
          };

          $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    $scope.collection.selectedImage = results[i];
                  window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile($scope.collection.selectedImage, function(base64){  
                        $scope.collection.selectedImage = base64;
                    });
                }
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        };  

        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.upload = function() {
              var link = 'http://example.com/upload.php';
              $http.post(link, {username : "xyz"}).then(function (res){
              $scope.response = res.data;
              console.log($scope.response);
        });
    };
})
```

Server Side

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    
    }


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        
            {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }


    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $username = $request->username;

        if ($username != "") {
            echo "Server returns: " . $username;
            require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = "support@example.com";  // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
            $mail->From = "support@example.com";
            $mail->FromName = "Example";
            $mail->AddAddress("abc@example.com", "ABC");
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;
            //$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = "New List Uploaded";
            $mail->Body    = $username;
            $mail->AltBody = "Alternate Body";

            if(!$mail->Send())
            {
                echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                exit;
            }
            echo "Message has been sent";
        }
        else {
            echo "Empty username parameter!";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: hello so you are facing problem uploading image on server ?

Comment: Hey!Kind of. How can i pass $scope.collection.selectedImage to server? I don't want to upload the image to the server at all.I just want to pass the image to the PHPMailer class and mail it.

Comment: I have no idea at all about how this can be done.A descriptive note will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have based your code on an obsolete example and you're running an old version of PHPMailer, so I suggest you [update it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/). I'd also recommend using composer to load your PHP libraries.

PHPMailer includes [an example script](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) that shows how to handle a form with a file element and email it.

This is the important part:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer simple file upload and send example
 */
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    // First handle the upload
    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // Upload handled successfully
        // Now create a message
        // This should be somewhere in your include_path
        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
        $mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
        $mail->msgHTML("My message body");
        // Attach the uploaded file
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg = "Message sent!";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
?>
```

The only complication I can see is that your file data will not be in $_FILES - you need to be sure that your decoded JSON submission actually contains what you think it does, so validate everything before you use it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! How can i send $scope.collection.selectedImage as a json data?

Answer (score -2):

```
function getPhotoFromGallary(source) {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadProfileImage, onFailGallary, {
                  quality: 50,
                  destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                  correctOrientation: true,
                  sourceType: source }
                                           );
              }

              function onFailGallary(message) {
                // alert('Failed because: ' + message);

              }

        function uploadProfileImage(imageURI) {
                console.log(imageURI);
                var UserId = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
                var img = document.getElementById('profileImageId');
                img.src = imageURI;
                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey="file";
                options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://androidmobiapps.com/longspan/webservices/uploaduserimg?user_id="+UserId+""), winProfile, failProfile, options);
              }
              function winProfile(r) {
                console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);

              }
              function failProfile(error) {
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
              }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to help users in the future.